# Problem using a for loop in a PHP nested array to it into separate arrays

Tags: php, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Am working on a nested array in PHP (From an API) which is 4 levels deep. Am trying to use a for loop to separate/dissect the nested arrays so that they may exist as independent entities so that I may use them in the blade. e.g **agency_sales , unit_sales, agents** When I dd on the browser, I get agency_sales while unit_sales I only get one array..

They are stored in a variable called rsm

**The array collection**

```
"regional_sales": [
    {
        "id": "75875",
        "agency_sales": [
            {
                "id": "157",
                "unit_sales": [
                    {
                        "id": "777",
                        "agents": [
                            {
                                "agent_no": "75939",
                                "policies": [
                                    "IL*********"
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "agent_no": "75939",
                                "policies": [
                                    "IL**********"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "111",
                        "agents": [
                            {
                                "agent_no": "758",
                                "policies": [
                                    "IL2*********"
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "agent_no": "75939",
                                "policies": [
                                    "IL20**********"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**My For loop**

```
for($a=0; $a < count($rsm); $a++){
    $asm = $rsm[$a]['agency_sales'];
    //dd($asm);
    for($b = 0; $b < count($asm); $b++){
        $usm = $asm[$b]['unit_sales'];
        dd($usm);
        for($c = 0; $c < count($usm); $c++){
            $ag = $usm[$c]['agents'];
            //dd($ag);
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you actually want to collect all the pieces at each level separately and then push down to generate the next level arrays. That will ensure you get all the values at each level into their respective array. This should work:

```
$asm = array();
for($a=0; $a < count($rsm); $a++){
    $asm = array_merge($asm, $rsm[$a]['agency_sales']);
}
print_r($asm);
$usm = array();
for($b = 0; $b < count($asm); $b++){
    $usm = array_merge($usm, $asm[$b]['unit_sales']);
}
print_r($usm);
$ag = array();
for($c = 0; $c < count($usm); $c++){
    $ag = array_merge($ag, $usm[$c]['agents']);
}
print_r($ag);
```

I've omitted the output as it is quite long but you can see it on the [demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/iqdph)

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to parse through such an array:

```
foreach ($data['regional_sales'] as $regional_sale) {
  // Access $regional_sale['id'] or anything else

  foreach ($regional_sale['agency_sales'] as $agency_sale) {
    // Access $agency_sale['id'] or anything else

    foreach ($agency_sale['unit_sales'] as $unit_sale) {
      // Access $unit_sale['id'] or anything else

      foreach ($unit_sale['agents'] as $agent) {
        // Access $agent['agent_no'] or anything else
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/q3dAR**

Comment: Thanks alot Jeto,, your answer is correct but Nick`s answer achieved my objective..